# How can I make my countdown reset every night at 16:00

Tags: javascript, php, timer, counter, countdown

I am working on a countdown for my website. We provide same day dispatch before 16:00 each day. I need a counter that will display a countdown to 16:00 each day.
Eventually, I will modify the code so that it doesn't display at all on the weekends but for now, all I need is something that can countdown everyday. Disappear after 16:00 and start fresh and countdown again from 00:00

Below is the code I have so far.

```
<?php
if (new DateTime() < new DateTime("16:00:00")) {

?>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var CDown = function() {
        this.state=0;// if initialized
        this.counts=[];// array holding countdown date objects and id to print to {d:new Date(2013,11,18,18,54,36), id:"countbox1"}
        this.interval=null;// setInterval object
    }

    CDown.prototype = {
        init: function(){
            this.state=1;
            var self=this;
            this.interval=window.setInterval(function(){self.tick();}, 1000);
        },
        add: function(date,id){
            this.counts.push({d:date,id:id});
            this.tick();
            if(this.state==0) this.init();
        },
        expire: function(idxs){
            for(var x in idxs) {
            this.display(this.counts[idxs[x]], "Now!");
            this.counts.splice(idxs[x], 1);
        }
    },
    format: function(r){
        var out="";
        if(r.d != 0){out += r.d +" "+((r.d==1)?"day":"days")+", ";}
        if(r.h != 0){out += r.h +" "+((r.h==1)?"hour":"hours")+", ";}
        out += r.m +" "+((r.m==1)?"min":"mins")+", ";
        out += r.s +" "+((r.s==1)?"sec":"secs")+", ";

        return out.substr(0,out.length-2);
    },
    math: function(work){
        var y=w=d=h=m=s=ms=0;

        ms=(""+((work%1000)+1000)).substr(1,3);
        work=Math.floor(work/1000);//kill the "milliseconds" so just secs

        y=Math.floor(work/31536000);//years (no leapyear support)
        w=Math.floor(work/604800);//weeks
        d=Math.floor(work/86400);//days
        work=work%86400;

        h=Math.floor(work/3600);//hours
        work=work%3600;

        m=Math.floor(work/60);//minutes
        work=work%60;

        s=Math.floor(work);//seconds

        return {y:y,w:w,d:d,h:h,m:m,s:s,ms:ms};
    },
    tick: function(){
        var now=(new Date()).getTime(),
        expired=[],cnt=0,amount=0;

        if(this.counts)
            for(var idx=0,n=this.counts.length; idx<n; ++idx){
                cnt=this.counts[idx];
                amount=cnt.d.getTime()-now;//calc milliseconds between dates

                // if time is already past
                if(amount<0){
                    expired.push(idx);
                }
                // date is still good
                else{
                    this.display(cnt, this.format(this.math(amount)));
                }
            }

            // deal with any expired
            if(expired.length>0) this.expire(expired);

            // if no active counts, stop updating
            if(this.counts.length==0) window.clearTimeout(this.interval);

        },
        display: function(cnt,msg){
            document.getElementById(cnt.id).innerHTML=msg;
        }
   };

   window.onload=function(){
      var cdown = new CDown();

      cdown.add(new Date(2015,9,16,16,00,00), "countbox1");
   };
 </script>
 <span style="font-size:30px;"><div id="countbox1"></div></span>
 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot format this properly, also I don't think it has pasted all of it. I will put this in a file online and share quick

Comment: Your problem will be that you'll have to leave the specific browser tab open all the time, since the interval will stop counting if someone closes the browser etc. I usually use a batch file to reopen the page and then use the standard task scheduler to run the batch file every day.

Comment: To make sure that the web visitor sees the correct time, use PHP to calculate how much time is remaining and feed this to your JavaScript code (as a function parameter). Otherwise the visitor will see a time based on their local machine clock (which might be minutes or hours different to your company clock). If you do this, make sure that the page will not be cached, otherwise visitors will see an outdated time remaining.

Comment: I think my problem is that line.
cdown.add(new Date(2015,9,16,16,00,00), "countbox1");

If I can automate the "2015,9,16" to display the current day, then I think it would work how I need it to.

Comment: Thanks Bobulous, I didn't think about the page caching.

Comment: cdown.add(new Date(<?php echo date("Y"); ?>,9,<?php echo date("d"); ?>,16,00,00), "countbox1");


-------------Would this work? Is there a php command that displays the month as 9, instead of 09?

Answer (score 0):

concept here testing
change the variable countDownTo to the current hour on line 8, 103  and 109
change the variable minute on line 133

```html
<?php if (new DateTime() < new DateTime( "16:00:00")) { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var check = 0;
  /*set the countdown hour*/
  var countDownTo = 16;
  var CDown = function() {
    this.state = 0; // if initialized
    this.counts = []; // array holding countdown date objects and id to print to {d:new Date(2013,11,18,18,54,36), id:"countbox1"}
    this.interval = null; // setInterval object
  }

  CDown.prototype = {
    init: function() {
      this.state = 1;
      var self = this;
      this.interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        self.tick();
      }, 1000);
    },
    add: function(date, id) {
      this.counts.push({
        d: date,
        id: id
      });
      this.tick();
      if (this.state == 0) this.init();
    },
    expire: function(idxs) {
      for (var x in idxs) {
        this.display(this.counts[idxs[x]], "Now!");
        this.counts.splice(idxs[x], 1);
      }

    },
    format: function(r) {
      var out = "";
      if (r.d != 0) {
        out += r.d + " " + ((r.d == 1) ? "day" : "days") + ", ";
      }
      if (r.h != 0) {
        out += r.h + " " + ((r.h == 1) ? "hour" : "hours") + ", ";
      }
      out += r.m + " " + ((r.m == 1) ? "min" : "mins") + ", ";
      out += r.s + " " + ((r.s == 1) ? "sec" : "secs") + ", ";

      return out.substr(0, out.length - 2);
    },
    math: function(work) {
      var y = w = d = h = m = s = ms = 0;

      ms = ("" + ((work % 1000) + 1000)).substr(1, 3);
      work = Math.floor(work / 1000); //kill the "milliseconds" so just secs

      y = Math.floor(work / 31536000); //years (no leapyear support)
      w = Math.floor(work / 604800); //weeks
      d = Math.floor(work / 86400); //days
      work = work % 86400;

      h = Math.floor(work / 3600); //hours
      work = work % 3600;

      m = Math.floor(work / 60); //minutes
      work = work % 60;

      s = Math.floor(work); //seconds



      return {
        y: y,
        w: w,
        d: d,
        h: h,
        m: m,
        s: s,
        ms: ms
      };
    },
    tick: function() {
      var now = (new Date()).getTime(),
        expired = [],
        cnt = 0,
        amount = 0;

      if (this.counts)
        for (var idx = 0, n = this.counts.length; idx < n; ++idx) {
          cnt = this.counts[idx];
          amount = cnt.d.getTime() - now; //calc milliseconds between dates

          // if time is already past
          if (amount < 0) {
            expired.push(idx);
          }
          // date is still good
          else {
            this.display(cnt, this.format(this.math(amount)));
          }
        }

      // deal with any expired
      if (expired.length > 0) this.expire(expired);

      // if no active counts, stop updating
      if (this.counts.length == 0) window.clearTimeout(this.interval);

    },
    display: function(cnt, msg) {
      if (msg == `Now!`) {
        check = 1;
        msg = ``;
        var cdown = new CDown();
        var currentdate = new Date();
        var year = currentdate.getFullYear();
        var month = currentdate.getMonth();
        var day = currentdate.getDate() + 1;
        var currenthour = currentdate.getHours();
        /*perform check here*/
        if (countDownTo == 16) {
          countDownTo = 0;
        } else {
          countDownTo = 16;
        }
        var hour = countDownTo;
        var minute = 0;
        var second = 0;
        cdown.add(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second), "countbox1");
      } else {
        check = 0;
      }
      if (countDownTo == 0) msg = ``;
      document.getElementById(cnt.id).innerHTML = msg;


    }
  };

  window.onload = function() {
    var cdown = new CDown();
    var currentdate = new Date();
    var year = currentdate.getFullYear();
    var month = currentdate.getMonth();
    var day = currentdate.getDate();
    var hour = countDownTo;
    var minute = 0;
    var second = 0;
    cdown.add(new Date(year, month, day, hour, minute, second), "countbox1");
  };
</script>
<span style="font-size:30px;"><div id="countbox1"></div></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a [cron job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) that will reset a variable once every 24 hours.

Comment: I wouldn't really know where to start with that

Comment: With PHP and JavaScript both available, cron jobs and system variables are wholly unnecessary for this purpose.

Comment: The script can control this and cron job is not required